# The significance of "return" in this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, restify

I am new to Javascript and following this tutorial: http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Error-handling

```
 server.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res, next) {
  return database.get(req.params.name, function(err, user) { // Why call "return" here?
    if (err)
      return next(err);

    res.send(user);
    return next();
  });
});
```

The 2nd line calls `return` although I tried without `return`, it also worked. Could someone shed a light here the significance of calling "return" here? Thanks.

Based on @Pointy's answer, I just would like to add that the question presumes "next()" function doesn't return any value.

Comment: The `return` is important whether or not "next" returns a value.

Answer (score 6):

The `return` statement causes a function call to exit at that point. If the statement includes an expression, then the function returns the value of the expression back to the calling environment.

In this case, the function in the first line (the `if` statement) detects an error, and so it passes that error along to its own callback (the function referred to by the "next" parameter). It then returns whatever that function returns.

Without the `return` statement on that line, the behavior of the function would be significantly different, so it doesn't actually "work" without it. It might work sometimes, but as that statement is involved in error handling you won't see the bug unless there's an error.

Comment: I see... So if I understand correctly, presuming "next()" doesn't return anything (I think it doesn't, looking at the doc), then would the code be significantly different without `return`?

Comment: Yes, quite significantly: the `return` statement causes the function to **exit** without performing any of the statements that follow it.

Comment: Ah I see... However, since `return` is the only statement in that function body, it doesn't make any difference with or wiithout it, does it? (apologize if I am being stubborn / insistent but just want to make sure if I get this).

Comment: If the first `if` test is `true`, then the function will call "next" and return whatever it returns, and it'll do so without going on to call `res.send(user)`.  That's the key point: `res.send(user)` is **only** called if the first `if` fails (that is, if there's no error condition detected).  If there *is* an error, then the function returns without calling `res.send(user)`.

Comment: @Pointy Can you clarify which return statement you're talking about, and whether the other return statements are redundant?

Comment: @fgb both `return` statements function the same way, but they appear at two different points in the code. A `return` statement means "return **right now**", so if the flow of execution makes it to the first `return` statement, nothing else in the function will be executed.

Comment: I think he's talking about the return statement that doesn't have anything after it (`return database.get...`), and wouldn't because it contains an asynchronous call. In that case, removing it wouldn't change the control flow.

Comment: @fgb it wouldn't change the control flow, but it would mean that the function would always return `undefined`. It's *usually* the case that return values from callback-type functions aren't important, but it's not *always* the case.

Comment: @fgb Thank you very much for clarifying. Yes, I meant the `return` in 2nd line ( `return database.get(...` ). Based on @Pointy's last comment, I think I can conclude that the `return` isn't significant  in this case. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't select this as an answer because the answer refers to the inner `return` where my question is pertaining to the `return` statement exactly on the second line.

Comment: @sleigner I think I have finally understood your question :)  I'm not exactly sure what that "outer" `return` is for; it clearly has something to do with a pattern expected by that Restify API, but the documentation does not make it clear. I would suggest asking the question in some forum more focused on Node stuff, or generalizing your question. The examples in that documentation don't seem consistent to me, but I may be looking at them incorrectly.